# C# httpClient.SendAsync does not send client certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code snippet:

```
var url  ="https://localhost/Sensor/Sensors/Whitelist";
var cerX509 = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\Client.pfx", "PASSWORD");
var messageHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
messageHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
messageHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cerX509);
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
```

I am trying to figure out why my client certificate is not being sent to the server when I call `httpClient.SendAsync(message)` and I receive an 401.

When I replace the call with `httpClient.GetAsync(url)` the certificate is being sent.

I have control over the server side code and I when I use `httpClient.GetAsync` I can retrieve the certificate with

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = request.GetClientCertificate();
```

when I am using `httpClient.SendAsync(message)` the method call `request.GetClientCertificate()` returns null.

Why is the SendAsync  not sending the certificate?

Comment: Are you awaiting on `httpclient.SendAsync`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes I do.

Comment: And is the response successful? Have you debugged the code?

Comment: Also, how are you creating `message`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I updated the question, based on your remarks

Comment: When debugging `GetAsync` and then `SendAsync`, are you getting the same responses? StatusCodes, etc?

Comment: Based on the certificate we authenticate the calling-party, so SendAsync  is returning 401 , GetAsync is returning 200

Comment: Considering `GetAsync` [internally calls `SendAsync`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64bde7a2046512f9fb53), I think we're missing something in your question.